# Geolocation rtweet search_tweet R

Tags: api, twitter, geocode

Does search_tweets function from rtweet package has parameters that allow me to filter by geolocation, equivalent to search_tweets parameter "geocode = '40.757343,-73.848261,40km'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, you need to download the tweets via `rtweet::search_tweets` and then impose a geographical cut on `coordinates`. Furthermore there is also a column entitled `bounding_box_coordinates` that can be proven useful to your analysis.